# Upgrading EE 2 with Zoo Visitor to EE 3 with Visitor

Tags: ee2, ee3, zoo-visitor

I'm trying to upgrade EE 2 with Zoo Visitor to EE 3 with Visitor 3.
However, I can't just copy over the add-ons directories because the names have changed from zoo_visitor to visitor.
Also in the database these changes exist.

Does anyone know how to upgrade?

Comment: Have you tried? Usually updates have mechanisms in place to update db Tables/rows. Setup a local Dev and try.

Comment: Yes, thats the problem. I did try and it gives all kind of errors because of the name change. I have also tried renaming all db tables/rows to exclude the word 'zoo' but no gain...

Comment: Save yourself some time and reach out directly to the Dev via contact form or Twitter

Comment: I did, no help. I had someone do it for me.

Comment: Do you know how this was solved Louis K? I've got the same problem - I bought a license in January and only just got around to starting the upgrade, and they won't support me outside of 30 days, which is almost as infuriating as this stackexchange site has become :)

Comment: Hey Bellamy, in the end I got a programmer to custom fix it for me. Its working now but I still had to make some tweaks to the code. The custom upgrade was not done correctly unfortunately. The code just isn’t written properly to start with and they’re probably not going to update it to work with ee4. I still don’t understand why the cms just hasn’t got these basic functions out of the box...